# Detect status of JBOSS standalone server

Tags: command-line-interface, jboss6.x

I would like to detect the status of the jboss standalone server using the CLI,

```
jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:10499 --command=":read-attribute(name=server-state)"
```

will return

```
{
"outcome" => "success",
"result" => "running"
}
```

If the server is running, but I would like to detect when the server is running "with errors".
When I in the log get something like:

```
JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) started (with errors) in 31474ms
```

The CLI command above returns the same result even if I get that message in the log. Someone know of another command I can use?

Comment: Did you found the solution to this? If so, please share :)

Comment: We decided to go another way so sorry no :(